# Execute FQL query with facebook c# sdk v6.0.10

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I would like to execute a FQL to retrieve all app user's friends.

In previous versions of the sdk it could be done with:

```
var client = new FacebookWebClient();
client.Query(String.Format("SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = {0})", me.id));
```

but with the version 6.0.10 I have no clue how can I do the same.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can actually get the same with Graph API call:

```
var client = new FacebookClient();
var query = string.Format("SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = {0})", me.id);

dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
parameters.q = query;
dynamic results = client.Get("/fql", parameters);
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to get the user facebook id like before: FacebookWebContext.Current.UserID?

Comment: Actually, where can I find some documentation? because everything is different now, and the official site doesn't provide complete documentation :(

Comment: It seems that the new place for the SDK (http://csharpsdk.org/)  doesn't have a complete documentation, just the basics. New documentation is just something in progress... For now you can dig into code to get more information, and build a help file (there is a documentation "project file" (for [Sandcastle Help File Builder](http://shfb.codeplex.com/)) located in `Build` folder of SDK sources.

Comment: @prabir fbClient.Query() - another feature ripped from the once great Facebook C# Library for us to figure out and implement ourselves :-/ why???  I basically need to take the code above and reimplement Query()

Comment: fql in rest api was difficult so we had that method. iwhen we moved to graph api we did some tricks to maintain the compatibility so you didn't have to change your code. you can read about fql changes at http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-What%E2%80%99s-new-in-v5-3.aspx It was better to break the compatibility sooner than later so we removed it in v6. You can see this ugly hack https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk/blob/a264af0703e07e6fceb930e98de6a2fdaa3b2eb2/Source/Facebook/FacebookClient.cs#L1273-1291 Feel free to create an extension method out of it.

Answer (score 25):

FQL

```
var fb = new FacebookClient("access_token");
dynamic result = fb.Get("fql", 
    new { q = "SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid=me()" });
```

FQL Multi Query

```
var fb = new FacebookClient("access_token");
dynamic result = fb.Get("fql", new
    {
        q = new[]
                {
                    "SELECT uid from user where uid=me()",
                    "SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid=me()"
                }
    });
```

FQL named multi-query

```
var fb = new FacebookClient("access_token");
dynamic result = fb.Get("fql",
    new
        {
            q = new
            {
                id = "SELECT uid from user where uid=me()",
                name = "SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid " +
                "IN (SELECT uid FROM #id)",
            }
        });
```